# Robolectric shadow activity.findViewById returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

## Robolectric shadow activity.findViewById returns a null.

This is fairly simple exercise. All the tuts are similar to this, so should be simple. Wondering if anyone else is experiencing this. Code is below.

```
@Test
public void shouldFindViewsById(){


    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(DeckardActivity.class).create().visible().get();

    assertThat(activity).isNotNull();

    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    assertThat(textView).isNotNull();

    Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);
    assertThat(button).isNotNull();

    EditText editText = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    assertThat(editText).isNotNull();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting you use the https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle example based on your DeckardActivity?

The original layout only contains a view with id `R.id.text`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello Espresso!"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

check that you import the correct example R class `import com.example.R;` and try just following test snippet:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(DeckardActivity.class).create().visible().get();

assertThat(activity).isNotNull();

TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
assertThat(textView).isNotNull();
```

if you like here is an extended example for robolectric tests https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template

Comment: I added another textview so that is not the issue. Does not work with the original 'R.id.text' either.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but when you start your example app, you will see your views on screen?

Comment: just to be clear we have the same: clone deackard-gradle; add assertThat(activity.findViewById(R.id.text)).isNotNull(); to existing test; then start tests with ./gradlew test <- works for me, can you reproduce this?

Comment: Just given up in the previous setup. Starting over with the one you have done. Looks good.